# Anything wrong with my code?

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, spinner

```
package one.two;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;


public class Booking extends Activity
{
    private DBAdapter db; 
    private Spinner colourSpinner;
    public Cursor c;
    public TextView txtArrival;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        db = new DBAdapter(this);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.booking);
        db.open();
        fillData();
        db.close();

        Spinner colourSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.myspinner);
    }

    private void fillData()
    {
        Cursor c = db.getSpinnerData();
        startManagingCursor(c);
        String[] from = new String[]{DBAdapter.KEY_ARRIVAL};
        int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter =
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.booking, c, from, to );
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
        Spinner colourSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.myspinner);
        colourSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener
    {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,int position, long id)
        {
            if (Booking.this.c.moveToPosition(position)) {
                String title=Booking.this.c.getString(1);
                Booking.this.txtArrival.setText(title);
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
}
```

Error log

```
 08-06 01:27:34.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(721): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-06 01:27:34.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(721): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-06 01:27:34.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(721):     at one.two.Booking$MyOnItemSelectedListener.onItemSelected(Booking.java:53)
08-06 01:27:34.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(721):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:856)
08-06 01:27:34.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(721):     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:41)
08-06 01:27:34.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(721):     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:827)
08-06 01:27:34.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(721):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-06 01:27:34.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(721):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-06 01:27:34.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(721):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-06 01:27:34.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(721):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
08-06 01:27:34.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(721):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 01:27:34.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(721):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-06 01:27:34.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(721):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
08-06 01:27:34.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(721):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
08-06 01:27:34.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(721):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Dont know if it has sth to do with your error but this looks strange to me: Booking.this.c.moveToPosition(position). Couldyou explain why/what is Booking.this *confused*

Comment: Can you provide a snippet to show where you are wiring up an instance of your `MyOnItemSelectedListener` to your list instance?

Comment: @InsertNickHere `Booking.this` is for scope resolution, it is valid code.

Comment: @Quintin Thanks. So its like :: in c++?

Comment: You now need to tell us what line 50 is.

Comment: boolean result = Booking.this.c.moveToPosition(position);
Line 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method fillData() you are creating a local Cursor object "Cursor c", which hides your class member "public Cursor c". You are initializing the local variable and when onItemSelected is called Booking.this.c will be null which gives you the NullPointerException.

Removing the "Cursor" part in fillData() should avoid this.

```
private void fillData()
{
   c = db.getSpinnerData();
   ...
}
```

Comment: After i removed Cursor, the error goes to line 53,  which is 
Booking.this.txtArrival.setText(title);

Comment: txtArraival has not been initialized either, so it is also null. If the TextView you want to use is within R.layout.booking you can add something like "txtArraival = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.'view_id');" in onCreate where 'view_id' should be replaced with the id you have.

Comment: Yea i added it to the oncreate method. Still a null error appears.
 TextView txtArrival = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtArrival);

Comment: Could you update the code as well? Also, it's hard to tell which line 53 is.

Comment: Lets continue this in your new question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `setOnItemSelectedListener` for your spinner with an instance of your custom class.. right now the code inside `MyOnItemSelectedListener` is not being invoked.

You can modify your `onCreate` to something like below.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    db = new DBAdapter(this);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.booking);
    db.open();
    fillData();
    db.close();

    Spinner colourSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.myspinner);
    //Set the OnItemSelectedListener for the Spinner
    colourSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
}
```

Comment: Ok let me try that, and i'll get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

If `Booking.this.c.moveToPosition(position)` returns false, you won't set any text. Are you certain it returns true?

You can check this by changing:

```
if (Booking.this.c.moveToPosition(position)) {
    String title=Booking.this.c.getString(1);
    Booking.this.txtArrival.setText(title);
}
```

to:

```
boolean result = Booking.this.c.moveToPosition(position);
if (result) {
    String title=Booking.this.c.getString(1);
    Booking.this.txtArrival.setText(title);
}
```

and use a debugger or a dialog box or something to display the value of result before you test it.

Comment: Sorry but how do i check if it returns true?